# A Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma for finite fields?

Tags: co.combinatorics, it.information-theory, pr.probability, measure-concentration

Given $m$ points in $\mathbb{R}^N$, the [Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson-Lindenstrauss_lemma) guarantees the existence of a linear operator $\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that nearly preserves pairwise distances between the points.  Here, we can take $n=\Omega(\log(m)/\varepsilon^2)$, where $\varepsilon$ is the level of distortion.

Is there a similar result for points in a vector space over a finite field, e.g. $\mathbb{F}_2^N$?  I assume a result of this form would be in terms of Hamming distance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Hamming distance is that it's bounded above by $N$, so if you have a subset of $\mathbb{F}_2^N$ with Hamming distances in that range, you're not going to be able to embed it in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ for $n$ much smaller than $N$.

Perhaps more natural is to build in a scaling, so that you want to find an embedding $f$ of the subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ in such a way that

$d(f(x),f(y)) \approx \frac{n}{N}\cdot d(x,y)$.

In other words, given two vectors $x$ and $y$, you want the *proportion* of coordinates in which they agree to be more or less left alone by the projection.  Then you could try a random projection as in Johnson-Lindenstrauss -- i.e. show that (if indeed this is true) a random choice of one of the $N \choose n$ coordinate projections gives you low distortion in this sense, when $n$ is not too horrifically small.

Comment: Agreed. Another way to address the scaling issue: Project onto an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^N$ and use Hamming distance in $\mathbb{F}_2^N$. I suppose a linear error-correcting code would provide a worthy subspace, but is there a randomized alternative that enjoys JL-type performance?

Comment: I think a truly random projection will scramble the Hamming distance too much - for instance, I don't see the need for there to be any correlation at all between the Hamming distance between two distinct points before and after the projection! Your only hope seems to be a random sparse projection.  But it's not clear to me how to make one such that the expected Hamming distance after projection, as a function of the Hamming distance before, is approximately linear. It seems like the best you can do is a convex curve.

Comment: In general, "distance" is rarely a useful concept over finite fields, as far as I know. What are you using this for? Is distance really accurate?

Comment: I don't know what a sparse projection is, but why not use a nonlinear projection?  I.e., find a point in the (random) subspace that is closest in Hamming distance?

Comment: 
How can scaling help?  $\{1,2,\dots, N\}$ embeds isometrically into  $F_2^N$, while in $F_2^n$ there are only $n$ distances.

Every finite subset of $L_1$ embeds into $F_1^N$ with arbitrarily small distortion (allowing scaling, of course) if $N$ is sufficiently large, so you are asking more than having $m$ element subsets of $L_1$ embed into `$\ell_1^n$` with $n$ small relative to $m$. Here there are negative results due to Brinkman-Charikar (simplified by Lee-Naor and further simplified by Schechtman and me). Only recently was it proved that $m$ element subsets of $L_1$ embed...

Comment: into `$\ell_1^n$` with $n \le \delta m$ with distortion depending only on $\delta$.

Comment: @Dustin: I mean just use a projection which, written in coordinates, is a sparse matrix. I don't know what a nonlinear projection is.